# Using bootstrap without the webpage resizing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm more of a backend learning to do frontend work..  I'm not much the designer so I've been learning Bootstrap, the only thing is I really only want it to work on desktop browsers.. when the browser website gets resized it starts looking really ugly and I don't want to spend the time to make it look nice when it starts get smaller / and on smaller devices as well.

Is there any way to disable the resizing?  Or is this just what Bootstrap does and there's no way around it?

I typically code everything as such:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    ....
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment yet and that's why I use answer option.

Did you try this: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive ?

Comment: perfect that's exactly what i was looking for.  thank you so much